# find input field where type=text in the table row

Tags: jquery

I have a delete image that that is triggered by a 'click' handler.  I'm passing the element parameter into the function that triggered the event, which is the delete image.

Is there a way I can find the input where `type="text"` for the table row that of the delete image that was clicked?

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
        A4J.AJAX.AddListener({
            onafterajax: function(req,evt,data) {  

                j$('[id$=deleteImage]').on('click', function(elem) {
                    console.log('the delete button was clicked');
                    console.log('************** before ' + localStorage.activeButtons);
                    var activeArray  = localStorage.activeButtons.split(',');
                    var idx = activeArray.indexOf('account');
                    if (idx > -1) activeArray.splice(idx, 1);
                    localStorage.activeButtons = activeArray.join(',');
                    console.log('************** after ' + localStorage.activeButtons);
                });

                var lastRow = j$('table[id$=participantTable] tbody tr:last');                 
                var active = localStorage.activeButtons.split(',');

                var dataRows = j$('tr.dataRow');
                dataRows.each(function(index, elem) {
                    updateImages(elem, active[index]);
                });
            }
        });
```

I need to find the `input[type="text"]` in the table row that the delete image was clicked and get the id of that input field and check if the id contains one of the following values: `contact, user or account`.  I need to pass the value contained in the input id into the indexOf() method.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

`j$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]:visible');`

inside the click handler

`j$('[id$=deleteImage]').on('click', function(elem) {`

jQuery [**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) - *get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.*

Comment: why not `j$(this).closest('tr')`, if there is more than one row with an input field?

Comment: that did find the correct row, but I didn't expect it to find the other inputs that were hidden.  So, it returned 3 inputs, but two of those inputs are hidden.  I only want the input that is visible.  Is there a way I can retrieve only the input that is visible?

Comment: I should clarify that it is a style attribute where `display:none` for those other two inputs that I don't want.

Comment: @Dman100, updated my answer adding `:visible`. Did you get it working?

Comment: yes, it is returning the correct row. Thank you!  Now, I'm trying to see if the input id contains the value ("contact", "user" or "account") and whichever value it contains, pass that into the indexOf() method.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the question:

```
 $("#TblName tbody tr input[type=text]").each(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });

    $("#TblName tr input[type=text]").each(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });

       $(".TblClass tr .InputClass").each(function(){
            console.log($(this).val());
        });
```